# Why won't the two main French far-left parties unite and present a single candidate?

Tags: presidential-election, parties, communism, france

*Lutte ouvrière* (LO) and *Nouveau Parti Anticapitaliste* (NPA) are both French far-left communist parties and they are both represented by a candidate during the French 2017 presidential elections, why aren't they presenting one single candidate ?

Are there fundamental ideological differences between the two parties, is it a partisan quarrel, or is there another reason ?

Comment: Because they know they are no chance of winning. Although I would imagine they would consider doing just that if they saw there was a chance.

Comment: Obligatory Monty Python reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WboggjN_G-4

Comment: That's a nice question. One of the main questions in French politics these days is why reformist far-left candidates Hamon and Melenchon unite and win the Presidential election? (Note: I call them reformist in opposition to Arthaud and Poutou, the candidates from the OP, that are openly in favor of general strikes and popular revolutions).

Comment: @Taladris I wouldn't label Hamon as far-left but the reason why he didn't withdraw is likely because of the necessity for the _Parti Socialiste_ to score at least 5% during the first turn (which they did) in order to [have 47% of their campaign expenses refunded by the French State](http://droit-finances.commentcamarche.net/faq/8904-le-remboursement-des-frais-de-campagne-presidentielle) (link in French). The PS would probably have been in a dire financial situation if they didn't get this refund.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One word answer : productivism.

The ideological roots of both parties are similar  (marxism). They both acknowledge that the climate should be preserved. However, they disagree on the extent to which it should be taken into account. LO wants to keep productivism, NPA does not.

[LO](https://www.lutte-ouvriere.org/) is a trotskist party. It is not opposed to producing a ton of material goods for the well being of the masses. It has an environmental agenda, but blames most climatic disasters (for instance fukushima) on the capitalist gestion of the production. The production of wealth itself should be kept.

[NPA](https://poutou2017.org/programme) does not claim to be a communist party. It wants to establish a "21st century ecological socialism ". It wants a control on the level of production, as well as on the technologies used to produce goods, in order to preserve the environment. Furthermore, controlling the level of production would enable to increase leasure time. This approach is similar to that of the [degrowth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrowth) theory, although the NPA does not avocate for reducing the growth, only choosing the proper level.

This leads to differences in their respective political agendas for the 2017 election. NPA is opposed to nuclear energy and GMOs, LO is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As someone interested in the politics of science and technology I also felt that the two parties differed in their attitudes on the subject. However NPA gave its support to the _Bonnets rouges_ movement in Brittany even though it is widely considered as right-wing since it was created in opposition to the _écotaxe_ (which supposedly goes into the direction of "cological socialism"). How to explain that ?